# What is the purpose of %new & %class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tweak

What do %new and %class mean in terms of MobileSubstrate tweaks? For instance:

```
%class TPBottomLockBar;
```

and

```
%new(v@:)
```

Sorry for double question!

Comment: Are you using Theos? Why don't you check the documentation, or ask on the IRC?

Comment: Hope this is useful http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Logos http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Special:AllPages

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are both Logos constructs. `%new` is for adding new methods to a class at runtime, and its syntax is `%new(typeencoding)`; you can get information on Objective-C type encodings [in Apple's Objective-C runtime documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html). Note that the first two arguments to these methods are always id and SEL, so the second two characters of your type encoding have to be "`@:`". The first character is the return type, and anything else is your set of custom arguments.

As an example, here is a pretty un-useful method:

```
%hook NSMutableString
%new(v@:)
- (void)appendAwesomeThings {
    [self appendString:@"Awesome."];
}
%end
```

(this will actually probably not work as NSString is a class cluster, but it serves as an example no less!)

`%class` is a deprecated directive for forward-declaring a class to be used at runtime; It's been replaced with `%c(ClassName)`, which is to be used inline.
For example,

```
[[%c(NSString) alloc] initWithString:@"Cool."];
```